# Are MySQL Batch statements executed in one block

Tags: mysql

When executing MySQL batch statements, are these processed in one block or still line by line within that batch?

I.e. if I have two queries in my batch, would it be possible for the server to process a query from a different connection in between those (hence potentially altering the data)?

An example:

```
    connect.setAutoCommit(false);
    statement.addBatch("INSERT INTO ArchivedEntries ("+fieldnames+") SELECT "+fieldnames+" FROM Entries WHERE IsOld IS NOT NULL");
    statement.addBatch("DELETE FROM Entries WHERE IsOld IS NOT NULL");
    statement.executeBatch();
    connect.commit();           
    connect.setAutoCommit(true);
```

I have multiple concurrent connections to the server. Would it be possible for a different connection to sneak in between these calls and potentially change IsOld in Entries table in between those two calls? This would mean that its not archived, but then deleted. Or can I be certain that both calls are guarenteed to be called in immediate succession?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having investigated "transaction" as per Vladmirs answer, I now believe that my original code above is actually safe.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

However, its nothing to do with batches, but instead the "magic" sits in the autocommit part of the code.

Based on the link above, I would also say that even without batches it should work without chance of interception:

```
connect.setAutoCommit(false);
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ArchivedEntries ("+fieldnames+") SELECT "+fieldnames+" FROM Entries WHERE IsOld IS NOT NULL");
statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM Entries WHERE IsOld IS NOT NULL");
connect.commit();           
connect.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> are these processed in one block

No.

> or still line by line

Yes.

> Would it be possible for a different connection to sneak in between these calls and potentially change IsOld

Yes it's possible. But you can use `transaction` to prevent this.

Comment: How do I use "transcation"?